# Consecutive named parameter problems in Hibernate (Spring HibernateTemplate)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring, parameters

I am trying to use named parameters to inject some strings into a query. I am using spring and hibernateTemplate, and and I am fairly new to Hibernate. I have gotten unnamed and named parameters to work in the past, but it seems as though when they are right next to each other they throw an error. I have made similar example code to my problem below (simplified to highlight the problem at hand). orderBy contains a string of a field and orderDirection contains ASC or DESC.

```
public List<HashMap<String, Object>> exampleList(String orderBy, String orderDirection) {
    logger.debug(orderBy);
    logger.debug(orderDirection);

    final String queryString =  "SELECT new map("+
                                "a.id AS id, "+
                                "a.name AS name, "+
                                "a.number AS number ) "+
                                "FROM Asset a "+
                                "ORDER BY :orderBy :orderDirection";

    String[] parameterNames = {"orderBy", "orderDirection"};
    Object[] parameterValues = {orderBy, orderDirection};

    List<HashMap<String, Object>> results = (List<HashMap<String, Object>>) hibernateTemplate.find(queryString, parameterNames, parameterValues);

    return results;
}
```

The console debugs my parameters:

```
DEBUG: com.myOrg.myProject.asset.AssetDAO - a.id
DEBUG: com.myOrg.myProject.asset.AssetDAO - desc
```

And I know this query would run fine on its own, as I have tested it with putting the values directly into the query string. I know that this is bad practice and can expose me to injection which is why I am not doing that.

The error I get is as follows (stack trace is shortened for ease of reading, but this is the only error and I can provide full stack trace upon request):

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dmat3 threw exception
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 118 [SELECT new map(a.id AS id, a.name AS name, a.number AS number ) FROM com.gsipt.dmat3.asset.Asset a ORDER BY :orderBy :orderDirection]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:914)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at com.myOrg.myProject.asset.AssetDAO.exampleList(AssetDAO.java:142)
    at com.myOrg.myProject.navigator.NavigatorController.assetGrid(NavigatorController.java:163)
```

Again, this works just fine when there are separate parameters, but when they are placed together this happens. The same error can be recreated using unnamed parameters only the "unexpected token" is the second "?" in the query string. How do I put two parameters, named or unnamed, next to each other as would make sense in an ORDER BY statement.

Thanks,
-Cliff

Answer (score 1):

You are using `find`, not

`findByNamedParams`

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#findByNamedParam%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).  For the Spring 3 API, see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/).

Also note that the HibernateTemplate documentation says

> NOTE: As of Hibernate 3.0.1,
>   transactional Hibernate access code
>   can also be coded in plain Hibernate
>   style. Hence, for newly started
>   projects, consider adopting the
>   standard Hibernate3 style of coding
>   data access objects instead, based on
>   SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().

Comment: Understood, but doesn't fix it unfortunately. Actually, the version I pasted with 'find' was a mistake because I had been attempting to debug something, I have used findByNamedParam and got the same error. I even tried it just now at your reccomendation and got an identical error.

Comment: hvgotcodes: Do you have any examples of a DAO based on SessionFactory.getCurrentSession?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use parameters (named or positional) in the ORDER BY clause. You can only use them in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to parameterize these anyway? As long as the values for `orderBy` and `orderDirection` are not coming from user input, you can safely just concatenate the values into the query.

```
if orderDirection == Sort.ASC) {
    queryString += " ASC";
}
else {
    queryString += " DESC";
}
```

etc

Comment: I could do that, but it is not purely injection I am worried about. I would like to know why it does not perform what looks to be a pretty simple operation properly and what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Params are for specifying **values** not for builing up sql syntax. Just concat the strings.